# Rails Add rolify role via user form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I'm creating an application based on Devise, CanCan and Rolify to handle private resources.

Devise registration has been disabled since I don't want allow users to registrer, while I'm creating an admin interface to add/edit users.

Now I'm dealing with user role. I'd like to allow admin to create users and set their role using the same form. I don't know what kind of relation is using rolify because I'm pretty new to rails and Ruby and rolify added the `rolify` method instead of a more clear relation.

I currently need and want to only have one role per user. So if someone edits the user changing the role I delete all `@user.roles` and then set the new one.

I'm currently having it to work using a simple hack.
I've added a select field to the form, using a collection of `Role`s to provide a selection of roles. Then inside the `create` and `update` methods I'm doing this:

```
role = params[:user][:role]
params[:user].delete :role
@user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save # update_attributes inside update
    @user.add_role role
    # ...
  end
end
```

As you may see I'm not interacting with the `Role` model directly but using the provided `add_role` method. This also creates another issue, because I have to retrieve the current role to allow the update view to set the proper default value for the select (beside the most important fact that I don't know how to validate the presence of ONE role).

This is going to be a too dirt solution, so I'd like to have some point of view, and maybe some suggestion on how to do this. I've spent all the day working on this :-(

If you need some info please ask me.

P.S. I'm watching a screenscast about nested resources but in the DB I may see that it's using a third table to keep track of `users_roles` and I'm not understanding how to do it.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I preferred to drop off Rolify.
It was taking too much time for me, and I realized I need a much simpler solution so I'm now using a new column in my model describin the user, and I've also implemented a method similiar to has_role? to keep compatibility with CanCan.

This has solved a lot of problems, and it's a more common solution (= easier help).

In my experience I noticed that if nobody answer your question on SO whithin 30 minutes, then you're doing it too complex.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: lol... i ended up going your way, Rolify Gem was taking too much time to figure out.

Comment: lol, nice one. It still remains a valid tool, I'm sure, but for simple things I think it's much easier to create a simple string/integer field.